# Facebook dilema; how to remove all members and add them back again, via PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Facebook forbids changing a group's privacy level (public, closed & secret) if the number of members exceeds 250! And I am trying to change a group's privacy setting from secret to public, but there are 27K members standing in the way!

So, I thought, why not make a list of the members, remove them from the group and invite/add them back, ... programmatically of course, with PHP ?!

Now, before even getting into Facebook API fuss, is it even possible ? would FB allow me to get a list of all the members ~> remove them ~> add them back ?! I THINK NOT.

Have anyone take on this challenge before ? Have you a tool that can help me do just that ? Or just export the members IDs, so I can invite them back after deleting the members manually (yes, if I had too).

Comment: No, that is not possible via API. Easiest option: Make a pinned post in the group, and tell all members they should please join the new, open group you create beforehand …

Comment: I JUST HATE FACEBOOK FOR THIS. WHY FACEBOOK WHY ?! :(

Comment: At least for the change from closed/secret to public, it is a sensible privacy measure. Imagine you were part of a such a closed/secret group, where you and other like-minded individual discuss how much you enjoy {insert-whatever-weird-fetish-you-can-think-of-here} – and all of a sudden a group admin goes, “ha ha, I’ll make this group public now, and expose all members for the weirdos they are!” – would _you_ like that …?

Comment: @CBroe hhh, makes sense. But the guy (it's a girl actually) who created the group had no idea what she is doing, she just picked what made her feel more "secure" haha